# Clean sphere separation with a sphere created from a cube

Tags: mesh

I would like to achieve a clean sphere separation with a sphere created from a cube.

Actually i got some kind of hatched egg effect, but that's not what i need

I was able to achieve that from an UV sphere, but i don't like the pinching effect at the pole :
When textured, i need the sphere to react with lighting effect the same way everywhere. The sphere  will be spinning in a webgl application, and the pinching effect at the pole will be visible.

Is there a way to do it?

I guess i need to add vertices to permit this separation. I tried to play a bit with the knife tool but without success so far.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be honest with you this seems a bit pointless. Could you maybe expand on the reason you don't like the pinching at the poles? You can increase topology density. If you need some sort of different topology for some specific forms it is hard to advise without knowing what those forms are - what you are trying to model and when and why the regular sphere geometry becomes a problem. I think the question would benefit greatly if you explained all the context and reasons for this.

Comment: @MartinZ i added the context in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Martin Z says, you don't say enough about your problem, also, what problem did you meet with the knife? To cut with the knife, press <kbd>K</kbd> for activate, then <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, then <kbd>C</kbd> to cut orthogonally

But if we keep your request, it looks like if you select an edge loop (<kbd>alt</kbd> right click), then scale it to 0 on the Z axis with <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>, then <kbd>W</kbd> > *LoopTools* > *Circle*, it works fine. Don't forget to activate the *LoopTools* addon in the Preferences.

And to separate a mesh in two parts, select the edge loop and press <kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: It could be just what i need. I'll be able to test that a bit later.
I don't know anything about blender, so i did not knew about the edge loop possibility

Answer (score 0):

1. make a straight line from a curve or mesh
2. go into a flat, orthographic view
3. place the line so it's where you want the cut to be on the sphere/cube
4. Select the line first, and Shift select the cube second
5. Go into Edit mode, and in the Tools Tab, press Knife Project. You need to check the box, Cut Through, so the new edges go right around. You won't see the cut until you move the view a little as it's lying directly under the line.
6. select all the top polys and press P/Selection.  When you come out of Edit mode you have the two pieces

Comment: Might be easier to just use bisect if it's a straight line.

Comment: or press K for knife, then Z to cut through, then C to cut orthogonally